# RPM package download to use a specific provider

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to install package A which has a dependency of Package B, and Package B has 2 providers, When I install package A, can we specify in the spec file which provider to be used to download package B when it’s being installed as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

When you say "provider" - do you mean "repository?" If so, no.

A workaround would be to repackage the RPM with a different `%dist` tag, and then by explicitly calling that out, you would force it to use the version from your local repo. But that would be a rabbit hole that's probably not worth running down.